# Python - While statement doesnt produce when false statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

```
things = ["shorts", "pen", "pencil"]
userthings = input("what do you want to find?")
userthings = userthings.lower()
bagged = False
for i in things:
    if i == userthings:
        bagged = True

if bagged == True:
    print ("I has thing")
else:
    print ("I dont has thing")        

morestuff = input("Do you want to add anything else?")
morestuff = morestuff.lower()

while (morestuff == "yes" or "y"):
    stuff = input("What do you want to add?")
    str(stuff)
    things.append(stuff)
    print ("I have the following things:", things)
    morestuff = input("Do you want to add anything else?")
else:
    print ("Lol bye")
```

My problem is the while statement code, when I input "no" into `morestuff`, or anything other than `"yes"` or `"y"` it doesn't print `"Lol bye"` but carries on with the `stuff = input("What do you want to add?")` statement and goes in an infinite loop.

Comment: The reason for your error is that Python sees `morestuff == "yes" or "y"` as `(morestuff == "yes") or ("y") `. Unless you type "yes", `(morestuff == "yes")` will evaluate to `False`, and you are left with `False or "y"`, which evaluates to `"y"`. When `"y"` is treated as a Boolean, it evaluates to `True`. If you type "yes", `True or "y"` evaluates to `True` as well. So your loop will continue forever.

Comment: Even if you had tried something like `morestuff == ("yes or "y")` it still wouldn't have worked properly though, because `"yes" or "y"` evaluates to simply `"yes"`, so only an input of "yes" would have made your code continue.

Answer (score 0):

`y` will always evaluate to `True` and mean that your loop never ends. Instead do

```
while (morestuff == "yes" or morestuff == "y"):
```

or more idiomatically

```
while (morestuff in ("y", "yes")):
```